# Text not updating after changed value of data in react native

Tags: react-native

```
      {dataList.map((item) => (
        <View style={[styles.popularCardWrapper]}>
          <View style={styles.popularCardLeft}>
            <Image source={item.image} style={styles.popularCardImage} />
          </View>

          <View style={styles.popularCardRight}>
            <View styles={styles.popularCardTopRight}>
              <View style={styles.popularTopWrapper}>
                <Image source={vegicon} style={styles.vegicon} />
                <View style={styles.ratingWrapper}>
                  <MaterialCommunityIcons
                    name="star"
                    size={10}
                    color={colors.secondary}
                  />
                  <Text style={styles.rating}>{item.rating}</Text>
                </View>
              </View>

              <Text style={styles.popularTitlesTitle}>{item.title}</Text>

              <Text style={styles.popularTitlesWeight}>
                in {item.title}
              </Text>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity
              key={item.id}
              onPress={() => onAddPress(item)}
            >
              <View style={styles.popularCardBottom}>
                <View style={styles.addPizzaButton}>
                  {item.value == 0 && <Text>ADD+</Text> }
                  {item.value != 0 && <Text>- / +</Text>}
                </View>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      ))}
```

In the above code, after pressing on the view which acts like a button (Touchable Opacity), The value of item increases and therefore the data changes. I have read that react renders the page only once in the beginning and therefore, the text does not change even though the actual data has changed. To solve this, I have tried using useState but since my screen has many items, after clicking on one item, the text also changes for the rest of the items which is not desired. How can I change the text for only one item that is selected without affecting others?

Answer (score 0):

1 Declare state

2. Create a method
3. Apply method on button

   ```js
   //declare state
   [value,setValue] = useState(1)
    
    //handle increment
    const onAddPress = () => {
    setValue(value+1)
    }
    
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onAddPress}>
       <View style={styles.popularCardBottom}>
         <View style={styles.addPizzaButton}>
           {value == 0 && <Text>ADD+</Text> }
             {value > 0 && <Text>You have added this item</Text>}
         </View>
       </View>
   </TouchableOpacity>
   ```

Comment: I did already applied what you are saying. I cannot replace the item.value with a single state variable. Please look at the complete code I have edited.